# Gradle 'Build Script error' occurs when I attempt to use testCompile in dependencies

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm working with Android Studio and in my dependencies for my application I attempting to add a testCompile dependency as listed here: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html
When I sync my file I get the error:
[image: sync error screenshot] I don't understand what is going on, my gradle build file in my root folder is set to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'` and that's the most recent version. Why doesn't it recognize testCompile? I don't want to deploy test dependencies to production... Any helps would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the project build file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()


    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and here is the src build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.edu.myApp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug{
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/scribe-1.3.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
    // Can't be higher than 19 if we want to support smaller android versions
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    // This Mockito includes all dependancies (great for us)
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.+"
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
    testCompile 'org.objenesis:objenesis:1.2'
}
```

Comment: Please add your build files to your question.

Comment: I don't see a testCompile statement in there.

Comment: Its simply because I removed it, I had test compile for the last 3 dependencies, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use `androidTestCompile`, not `testCompile`. If this is due to modifying the dependency scope via the Project Structure dialog, then there's a bug where it uses the wrong statement to set up the dependency. I've filed https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74771 for this.

Comment: **This is not the right answer.** Switching to `androidTestCompile` is very different to `testCompile`. The later is useful for pure unit tests that simply requires the JVM as opposed to an emulator or device which `androidTestCompile` is for. See [Louis Morda's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30039571/80428) which involves updating gradle.

Comment: @JayWick I've flipped the answer over to community wiki to encourage folks to edit it and correct it if necessary.

Answer (score 9):

I stumbled upon this post a year later.  I was having this problem because I inherited an older project that was using an out-of-date Gradle build tools setting in the Gradle build file.  I fixed this problem by updating Gradle build tools, which you need to do apparently by incrementing the version number in the Gradle build file:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.X.X'
}
```

where X.X is the latest gradle build tools version number. Right now I'm using Android Studio v1.2 and I've got my build tools version number set to:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.2'
}
```

I came across this problem when I was trying to implement unit tests, which are now built-in to Android Studio apparently.

Hope this helps someone with the same problem.

Comment: Yup, this was exactly my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I got this "method not found 'testcompile()'" error also. The problem was I had testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' in my project build.gradle file and not in by app build.gradle file. How could I have known it was in the wrong file? The project file only states "NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong in the individual module build.gradle files". Such a simple answer no wonder I couldn't find it.

Comment: You could refer to solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368203/how-to-use-mockito-hamcrest-in-unit-tests-in-android-studio

Comment: Thanks for this. The docs even state `In your app's top-level build.gradle file` which is quite unhelpful. https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html

Answer (score 0):

I have a library project.  I believed the Android documentation and put the `testCompile` statement in my top level `build.gradle` file. Turns out it actually had to go in my module `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.example.listview;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList<String> arrnames=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> arrids=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> arrlang=new ArrayList<>();
ListView Listview;
Spinner spinner;
AutoCompleteTextView act;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Listview=findViewById(R.id.listview);
        spinner=findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        act=findViewById(R.id.autotext);
    arrnames.add("jua");
    arrnames.add("sbalena");
    arrnames.add("roose");
    arrnames.add("saa");
    arrnames.add("linda");
    arrnames.add("lee");
    arrids.add("adhar card");
    arrids.add("pan card");
    arrids.add("license card");
    arrids.add("ration");
    arrids.add("score card 10th");
    arrids.add("score card 12th");
    arrlang.add("c++");
    arrlang.add("c");
    arrlang.add("java");
    arrlang.add("kotlin");
    arrlang.add("html");
    arrlang.add("css");
    arrlang.add("javascript");
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinneradapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,arrids);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinneradapter);
    ArrayAdapter<String> auto=new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrlang);
    act.setAdapter(auto);
    act.setThreshold(1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrnames);
    Listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    Listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(position==0){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item 1 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (position==1) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item 2 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).